# How to use $project on the returned nested array after $lookup?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections in MongoDB and I like to use $lookup to mapping two collections and return specific values.

One collect named job:

```
_id:ObjectId("123")
categories: [0: ObjectId(100), 1: ObjectId(200)]
....
```

another collect named job_categories:

```
_id:ObjectId("100")
name:'HR';
_id:ObjectId("200")
name:'BA'
```

I can use $lookup mapping these two collections by job_categories, how can use $project just to return the name value from job_categories.

Expected return result like this:

```
_id:ObjectId("123")
categories_names:['HR','BA'].

Any help please....
```

Comment: Generally speaking, it is helpful to include valid working JSON data in your question so people that want to help can test ideas.  You indicated you have successfully used $lookup.  Please include valid sample JSON data, and please include the successful aggregation you have created so others may assist you.

Comment: This question looks as duplicated as [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554612/how-to-use-project-return-nest-array-after-lookup-in-mongodb) from OP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use $project return nest array after $lookup in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554612/how-to-use-project-return-nest-array-after-lookup-in-mongodb)