# how to use $project return nest array after $lookup in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections in MongoDB and I like to use $lookup to mapping two collections and return specific values.

Job collection

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5b0d2b2c7ac4792df69a9942"),
    "title": "software engineer",
    "categories" : [
        ObjectId("5b0d16ee7ac4792df69a9924"), 
        ObjectId("5b0d47667ac4792df69a9994")
    ],
    "deadline": 2021-05-03T06:29:54.634+00:00
}
```

job_categories collection：

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId(5b0d16ee7ac4792df69a9924),
    "name": "front-end"
}
{
    "_id": ObjectId(5b0d47667ac4792df69a9994),
    "name": "full-stack"
}
```

The `objectid`in job collection `categories` array matches the `_id` of job_categories.
how to use $lookup and $project to return the following result.

Expected result:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5b0d2b2c7ac4792df69a9942"),
    "title": "software engineer",
    "categories" : [
        ObjectId("5b0d16ee7ac4792df69a9924"), 
        ObjectId("5b0d47667ac4792df69a9994")
    ],
    "deadline": 2021-05-03T06:29:54.634+00:00,
    "categories_list": [
        "front-end",
        "full-stack"
    ]
}
```

The expected result adds a new filed `categories list` and the array value reference `job_categories` collection's `name`key value.

Answer (score 1):

Just perform the `$lookup` directly. Then `$project` the field `$categories_list.name` as `categories_list`.

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZjMI3soLZt1) for your reference.